# how to get a product compare url in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, compare

I am trying to get compare url of a product.

For this i am using:

`<?php echo $_compareUrl=$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>`

Its output is `http://localhost/my_magento_folder/catalog/product_compare/add/`.

I am not getting the compare url with product id. It should be like `http://localhost/my_magento_folder/catalog/product_compare/add/product/3723/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC90d3Avd2lyZS1tZXNoLW1hdGVyaWFsL2JyYXNz/`.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at `compare.phtml` from below file path

`magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\addto\compare.phtml`

```
<a href="#"
   class="action tocompare"
   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
   aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
   data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCompareHelper()->getPostDataParams($block->getProduct()); ?>'
   role="button">
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
</a>
```

It means they are using `getPostDataParams()` method from compare helper, so you can also use same method to get the compare URL. Like below

```
<?php echo $_compareUrl=$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare')->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>
```